# Remember image number in JavaScript slide show across pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, slideshow

I have a pure html+JavaScript slideshow I am making.  The slideshow is in a sidebar of the website that is loaded with php for each page that has the slideshow sidebar.  The only page without the sidebar is the main page.

The slide show is working fine.  However, understandably, each time I go to a new page with the sidebar, the slideshow starts over.  Makes sense since the javascript reloads with each new page.

I would like to find some way to have the slideshow remember its place so that when I go to a new page the slide show just continues where it left off on the previous page.  I can only think of two solutions, one seem brute force, and one I don't know how to do:

1. Write the current image number to a file and read it each time the
   slideshow loads.
2. Somehow use ajax, but I haven't learned to use ajax
   yet (would it work?).

Any suggestions?  Oh, and please I'm learning javascript, jQuery and ajax are next, but...

Here is my code:

**simpleslideshow.html:**

```
<html>
```

initializeSlideShow();

```
<table width="100">
  <tr>
    <td align="left"> <div id="previous">  <a href="javascript:change_image(-1)">Previous</a></div></td>
    <td align="right">  <div id="next"><a href="javascript:change_image(1)">Next</a></div></td>
    <td align="right"> <div id="auto"><a href="javascript:auto()">auto</a></div></td>
    <td align="right"> <div id="stop"><a href="javascript:stop()">stop</a></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<img src="" id="slideshow-image" width="400px" height="auto" style="display:block;"/>
```

**simpleslideshow.js:**

```
var inaterval_ID = 0;
var image_number = 0;       
var num_images = images_with_captions.length;


function change_image(increment){
  image_number = image_number + increment;
  image_number = (image_number + num_images) % num_images;
  var string = images_with_captions[image_number].source;
  document.getElementById("slideshow-image").src = string;
}

function initializeSlideShow() {
  //var string = images_with_captions[0].source;
  //document.getElementById("slideshow-image").src = string;
  auto();
}

function auto() {
  interval_ID = setInterval("change_image(1)", 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval_ID);
}
```

**image_caption_list.js:**

```
var images_with_captions = new Array(
{
  source: "http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-435833.jpg",
  caption: "flower 1"
},
{
  source: "http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-511058.jpg",
  caption: "flower 2"
},
{
  source: "http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-380016.jpg",
  caption: "flower 3"
}
);
```

Edit:  I can't get a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/CbaK4/1/) to work.  But [here](http://arielbalter.com/cio/simpleslideshow.html) is a live version that may or may not be up for a while:

Comment: state saving basic choices are cookie or localStorage in client, or using ajax to server. Try cookie...very simple to implement. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the current slide value to either a cookie or localStorage each time you change to a new slide and then when you start up the slideshow on a new page, you can read the previous slide value and start from that slide number.

Here's reading the previous slide number:

```
function initializeSlideShow() {
  // get prior slideshow num
  var lastSlideNum = +readCookie("lastSlideNum");
  // if there was a prior slideshow num, set that as the last one we used
  if (lastSlideNum) {
      image_number = lastSlideNum;
  }
  auto();
}
```

Here's saving the slideshow number each time it changes:

```
function change_image(increment){
  image_number = (image_number + increment) % num_images;
  // remember what slide we're on for subsequent page loads
  createCookie("lastSlideNum", image_number);
  var string = images_with_captions[image_number].source;
  document.getElementById("slideshow-image").src = string;
}
```

And, here's a simple cookie library:

```
// createCookie()
// name and value are strings
// days is the number of days until cookie expiration
// path is optional and should start with a leading "/" 
//   and can limit which pages on your site can 
//   read the cookie.
//   By default, all pages on the site can read
//   the cookie if path is not specified
function createCookie(name, value, days, path) {
    var date, expires = "";
    path = path || "/";
    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=" + path;
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

---

A localStorage implementation (which would not remember the slide in IE versions before IE8) would look like this:

```
function initializeSlideShow() {
  // get prior slideshow num
  var lastSlideNum;
  // localStorage requires IE8 or newer
  // if no localStorage, then we just don't remember the previous slide number
  if (window.localStorage) {
      lastSlideNum = +localStorage["lastSlideNum"];
      // if there was a prior slideshow num, set that as the last one we used
      if (lastSlideNum) {
          image_number = lastSlideNum;
      }
  auto();
}
```

Here's saving the slideshow number each time it changes:

```
function change_image(increment){
  image_number = (image_number + increment) % num_images;
  // remember what slide we're on for subsequent page loads
  if (window.localStorage) {
      localStorage["lastSlideNum"] = image_number;
  }
  var string = images_with_captions[image_number].source;
  document.getElementById("slideshow-image").src = string;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was a lot of work you put into the answer.  The local storage method looks a lot simpler (and could care less about IE<8), but might be time for me to learn something about cookies.  I was able to follow most of it except reacCookie.  But if I read up on cookies, hopefully I'll figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: @abalter - `readCookie()` is just parsing a string like this: `lastSlideNum=29; optionsExpanded=1; background=blue` to find the value it's looking for.